# How to dynamically give ID to ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag-grid for dataTables. I have created a component which consists of ag-grid. A unique ID is passed as input to this component and I want to give this id as grid id.

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid class="ag-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[rowData]="rowData">
```

So i want to make this id `#agGrid` to be dynamic.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do use any of the following to set a unique id:

- `[id]="dynamicId"`
- `[attr.id]="dynamicId"`
- `id={{item.dynamicId}}`